# Order results by number of coincidences in edge properties

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm working on a recommendation system that recommends other users. The first results should be the most "similar" users to the "searcher" user. Users respond to questions and the amount of questions responded in the same way is the amount of similarity.

The problem is that I don't know how to write the query

So in technical words I need to sort the users by the amount of edges that has specific property values, I tried with this query, I thought it should work but it doesn't work:

```
   let query = g.V().hasLabel('user');

   let search = __;
   for (const question of searcher.questions) {
      search = search.outE('response')
            .has('questionId', question.questionId)
            .has('answerId', question.answerId)
            .aggregate('x')
            .cap('x')     
   }

   query = query.order().by(search.unfold().count(), order.asc);
```

Throws this gremlin internal error:

> org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.BulkSet cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex

I also tried with multiple `.by()` for each question, but the result was not ordered by the amount of coincidence.

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `cap()` an `aggregate()` it returns a `BulkSet` which is a `Set` that has counts for how many times each object exists in that `Set`. It behaves like a `List` when you iterate through it by unrolling each object the associated size of the count. So you get your error because the output of `cap('x')` is a `BulkSet` but because you are building `search` in a loop you are basically just calling `outE('response')` on that `BulkSet` and that's not valid syntax as `has()` expects a graph `Element` such as a `Vertex` as indicated by the error.

I think you would prefer something more like:

```
let query = g.V().hasLabel('user').
              outE('response');

let search = [];
for (const question of searcher.questions) {
  search.push(has('questionId', question.questionId).
              has('answerId', question.answerId));
}

query = query.or(...search).
              groupCount().
                by(outV())
              order(local).by(values, asc)
```

I may not have the javascript syntax exactly right (and I used [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in my `or()` to just convey the idea quickly of what needs to happen) but basically the idea here is to filter edges that match your question criteria and then use `groupCount()` to count up those edges.

If you need to count users who have no connection then perhaps you could switch to `project()` - maybe like:

```
let query = g.V().hasLabel('user').
              project('user','count').
                by();

let search = [];
for (const question of searcher.questions) {
  search.push(has('questionId', question.questionId).
              has('answerId', question.answerId));
}

query = query.by(outE('response').or(...search).count()).
              order().by('count', asc);
```

fwiw, I think you might consider a different schema for your data that might make this recommendation algorithm a bit more graph-like. A thought might be to make the question/answer a vertex (a "qa" label perhaps) and have edges go from the user vertex to the "qa" vertex. Then users directly link to the question/answers they gave. You can easily see by way of edges, a direct relationship, which users gave the same question/answer combination. That change allows the query to flow much more naturally when asking the question, "What users answered questions in the same way user 'A' did?"

```
g.V().has('person','name','A').
  out('responds').
  in('responds').
  groupCount().
  order(local).by(values)
```

With that change you can see that we can rid ourselves of all those `has()` filters because they are implicitly implied by the "responds" edges which encode them into the graph data itself.

Comment: I had to add .unfold() after .by(outV()) otherwise the order was incorrect like if the order() step was not working, after changing that it worked perfectly, so thank you very much!
I will improve the schema like you mentioned. Do you think the speed of the search could be multiplied by improving the schema? or both have more or less the same speed?

Comment: Also one more thing: Your query removes from the results all the users with 0 answer matches, I don't want them removed, just want them to be on the bottom of the results, is there a clean way to fix this? I fixed it with this ugly hack after the for loop:

`search.push(__.has('questionId', searcher.questions[0].questionId))`

That searches for a response edge that all users are going to have because is not filtering the response, so the or() step returns at least one edge per user so no users are removed

Comment: One more thing: Since I need all users on the result also the 0 matching users then is more difficult to follow your schema improvement advice, because in that advice these users will also be removed. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Regarding the `unfold()`, you could do that or just `order(local)` - I've updated my answer.

Comment: As for speed improvements as a result of changing the schema, it's hard to say, but I know you go from a global scan of all "person" vertices and their edges to an indexed lookup of a single "person" with a traversal to all the questions they answered followed by another step to the "person" vertices who answered the questions. Typically, that would be significantly "faster" but obviously a lot depends on the shape of your data.

Comment: A full graph scan of 1 billion vertices is not likely going to be faster than a traversal from a single vertex but even from a single vertex you could still lead to a traversal that has to touch a lot of data by analyzing tons of paths and be massively costly exceeding your performance expectations.

Comment: Regarding the need to show all users, I added an approach for your traversal that uses `project()`. Admittedly, showing all users doesn't' work well in my revised approach to the schema as they are not connected by edges to be returned in the traversal. I guess there are ways to union in those users as part of a single request and certainly with two separate traversals where you would just merge a full list of users into the result of my traversal. I guess the lesson here is that graphs are good when there are relationships between data and not so good when there are not.

Comment: The query you added that uses project works great except for `order().by('count', asc);` which I had to change adding a select() `order().by(__.select('count'), order.desc)` it was throwing `LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Element` thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: yes, that might be necessary on older versions of Gremlin. cosmosdb may not support my syntax yet but my approach works on the most recently released version of 3.4.6.

Comment: I'm working in localhost and I have 3.4.4 so it must be something added on 3.4.5 or 3.4.6